# How can you add the last elements in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, element

For example;

`eglist = [["a", 1, 2.3],["b",2,3.4]]`

I would not know how many lists there are in *eglist*. So, how can you add the last elements of each list in *eglist*, knowing that its type will be a float?

Here is my attempt:

```
addList = []
for i in eglist: 
    addList.append(eglist[-1])          
    print(i)
sum(addList)
```

However I get this error:

```
sum(addList)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Sorry if it's such a localised question, I couldn't find any answers that can help me. Thanks for helping.

Comment: `print(sum(i[-1] for i in eglist))` ?

Comment: Your code works. Just change `addList.append(eglist[-1])` for `addList.append(i[-1])`

Comment: @Rakesh You can even skip the creation of a list and just use a generator for improved efficiency `sum(a[-1] for a in eglist)`.

Comment: @ZiyadEdher. Thanks. I always forget that :)

Comment: Thanks! All of these solutions really helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you're accessing `eglist[-1]` each time.  That's always a list.  What you should do instead is access `i[-1]`:

```
addList = []
for i in eglist:
    addList.append(i[-1])
    print(i)
sum(addList)
```

Additionally, if you want to replace your loop with a one-liner:

```
addList = [ i[-1] for i in eglist ]
sum(addList)
```